# React UnitTest with Jest and Enzyme

Tags: reactjs, react-native, testing, jestjs, enzyme

I was surprised that many blogs are writing unit tests for React Applications using both Jest and Enzyme.
Cant, we write unit tests for React applications by using the only jest or by the only Enzyme??

If yes, to get a component we use shallow() in enzyme but what we use in Jest?

Comment: this should answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/69873282/6014755

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you didn't fully understand the concepts of `jest` and `enzyme`.

## Jest

**TL;DR:** Jest is just a test runner on steroids for JavaScript (not just `react`).

The main functionality of `jest` is to execute JavaScript tests. It gives you tools to organize your tests, e.g. using `describe`, `it` or `test` blocks. `jest` comes with a lot of [build-in assertions](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect) (e.g. `expect(actual).toBe(expected)`) to help you identifying failing and succeeding tests. On top of that `jest` comes with additional features, for example it allows you to easily [mock functions](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions) or even [complete modules](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions#mocking-modules).

`jest` is **not** bound to `react` in general, but does quite well in combination with `react`, since it is maintained by facebook just as `react` itself. So it's basically almost everytime the right joice and also [recommended by `react`](https://reactjs.org/docs/testing.html#tools).

## Enzyme

**TL;DR:** Collection of utilities to simplify testing/rendering `react` components.

Technically you don't need `Enzyme` or any other framework to test `react` components (only `jest`). `react` already exposes `react-dom/test-utils` but it's really cumbersome to work with those without properly wrapping and simplyfing its API. And that's exactly what `enzyme` is doing. It basically puts a layer of abstraction over `react-dom/test-utils` and adds a bunch of utilities, so you don't need to worry about implementing them yourself.

---

**I highly recommend** you to look at [`react-testing-library`](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/intro), an alternative to `enzyme`, and read ["Testing Implementation Details" blog post](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/testing-implementation-details) authored by its founder.
`react-testing-library` is, like `jest`, [recommended by `react`](https://reactjs.org/docs/testing.html#tools).

Answer (score 1):

**Jest** and **Enzyme** are not comparable.

Jest don't give you rich API/function to access dom elements like enzyme but it does other important tasks like when you hit command `npm test` or `npm run test` jest collect all the test file eg all files ending with .test.js run each test cases within these files and show the result in the console like below its jest responsibility.

[image]

Jest is a testing framework or test runner which runs all the test files in one go, enzyme is a utility or library consider this a smaller thing compare to jest it gives many functions to access dom easily like `shallow, mount, find, children, etc...`